# When does the browser execute the CONNECT method?

Tags: http, httpconnection, http-method

In http we have a method called CONNECT. I am trying to understand when it is used by the browser.

Is it used prior to every request or prior to every **https** request only?

Further, as we know - the http protocol makes persistent connection with the server. This connection gets closed after a certain period of inactivity or timeout. So does this concept influence when the CONNECT method is used by the browser? That is - whether CONNECT is used prior to each persistent connection or prior to each request within the persistent connection?